# Ajax Call too late... Giving result after 15 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have jquery datepicker which gives the events list when selected  date through ajax call from database.. when i click on the date the result is getting displayed too late after 15 seconds...can any 1  suggest me what to do to get the result on clicked fastly:-

```
var x = '';
$('#calendar').datepicker({

    altField: '#datepicker_send',

    inline: true,

    firstDay: 1,

    showOtherMonths: true,

    altFormat: "yy/mm/dd",

    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",

    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],

    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        $('#event-date').text(dateText)
        x = dateText;
        //alert(x);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'check_events.php',
            data: 'y=' + x,

            success: function (data) {
                $('#event-date1').html(data); //Alert Data on success not result.
                // alert(data);
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Check_events.php:-``

```
<? php

if (isset($_GET['y'])) {

    $y = $_REQUEST['y'];

    $sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date='$y'");

    $res = mysql_num_rows($sql_check);

    if ($res == 0)

    {
        echo '<div class="evnt_name"><a href="#">No Events For Today <a/> </div>';

    } else

    {

        while ($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_check))

        {

            ?>

            < div > Some Result < /div>
  <?php } 
   } 
} 
exit; ?>
```

Comment: Sounds like it's just your database holding you up - tried adding an index on the `date` column so its `SELECT` is faster?

Comment: i have tried the same code in local xampp.. its working perfectly and the ajax call is giving its results in milliseconds... i dint used any index for date column over there !!!

Comment: And i also read some where that Index should not be used for small tables.... my table data is very small...can i use it for my "date" column ?

Comment: Check your db connection, I have had issues before where using the 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost gave a quicker response time, which may explain why it's working ok with xampp

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming your table must be large, but it must be some sort of connection issue if it's a small table.

Comment: @JLevett :- dint get u...can u please elaborate ur answer what to do with db connections to get quicker responses from db

Comment: @EvanKnowles: do u have any idea of what type of connectuin issues may occur !!!

Answer (score 0):

i think @JLevett is suggesting to change your host name from localhost to 127.0.0.1 in mysql connection string. Also specify field name in select query rather than * , it is in not much of a performance improvement but it will help.

Comment: i have a differnet hostname .. am not using localhost in server db connections.....changed the select query specifying required column names rather than * but no change in the performance.....

Comment: have you tried running the page in your browser directly yoururl/Check_events.php?y=2014-11-6

Comment: ya tried with the url/check_events.php?y=2014/11/14... time of execution reduced little bit but no use...

Comment: i meant, have you opened that page in a browser if yes and the page is loading slowly then its the issue with your host.

Comment: yes i have opened results page individually with date  in browser....and it is littlebit slow ... not that much slow when compared with the execution of calender page....